# Unable to connect to MYSQL Database with a DB Instance Running on AWS

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect DB instance on AWS. There are proper security groups rules added to it. The person who created the instance is able to connect. However, I cannot. Here is the error message I continually get. Any suggestions to why? I am sure the password, hostname, and username is correct. I have redownloaded MYSQL Workbench twice now.

[image: My Error Message Image]

I tried redownloading MYSQL Workbench.
The endpoint is the hostname.
The username and password are also correct.

Comment: Something is very confusing in the error message. It says it failed to connect to the AWS instance, but then says "Unable to connect to localhost".  I'm not sure how localhost fits into this.